# Finding the value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ using Fourier transformation of a function f(x)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

$f(x)=|x+\frac{\pi}{2}|-2|x|+|x-\frac{\pi}{2}|$

After using Fourier transformation I get

$a_0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$

$a_n = \frac{8}{\pi n^2}sin^2(\frac{n\pi}{4})$

$f(x)= \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} a_n*cos(nx)$

After this of I substitute n=2k and k=2h+1 I can get values but not for the sum in question. Is it even possible to solve this?

Comment: Can this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8378/505767

Comment: this is not a Fourier transform, is the Fourier series of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your calculation is true. You found
$$f(x)= |x+\frac{\pi}{2}|-2|x|+|x-\frac{\pi}{2}| =\frac{\pi}{4} + \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{8}{\pi n^2}\sin^2(\frac{n\pi}{4})\cos(nx)$$
let $x=0$ then
$$\frac{3\pi}{4} = \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{8}{\pi n^2}\dfrac12\left(1-\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$$
or
$$\frac{3\pi^2}{16} = \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\left(1-\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$$
we may let $n=4k, 4k+1, 4k+2, 4k+3$ and after simplification, only terms with $n=4k+2$ remain. Can you proceed from here?